# OSGi service and MVC pattern best practice

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, osgi

Let's suppose I have two osgi bundles. There is mvc pattern in each bundle. View - swing JFrame. What is the best practice to communicate between these two components? As I see there are two ways:
1) In service we do service function and inside this function we call controller function. Something like that

```
Class MyService {
    public void readSomething(){
      controller.readAction();
    }
}
```

2) Or service may return controller and the other component will use this foreign controller. Something like that:

```
Class MyService {
    public Controller getController(){
      return controller;
    }
}
```

I'd like to know what other people use and think.

Comment: Is this for a Swing app or for a JEE app? Or something that is generic to OSGi?

Comment: @Tassos Bassoukos Something that is generic to OSGi as I use osgi and for javaee and for javase. And everywhere MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it depends :-).

I assume you have two components `A` and `B`, and component `A` needs to notify component `B` of something, or, in other words, component `B` is interested in something that happens in component `A`.

One way for the components to cooperate is to use the *`EventAdmin`* service; component A emits events for all possible cases, and component B has registered an `EventHandler` with an appropriate filter for these events. Bonus: component `A` can specify sync/async handler execution, and there may be multiple components that will be notified without any extra overhead. Both `A` and `B` need not be services or even objects, if the bundle activators handle all the wiring.

Another way is to use `Declarative Services`: components `A` and `B` are objects, and you have defined an interface `IB` that specifies the valid operations on `B`, and which `B` implements. `A` is marked as needing at least one `IB`, and the DS service will instantiate both and invoke methods on A with the proper IB references. A can then normally call methods of IB.

As a simplification of DS, you can use normal services: A isn't a service, but it finds instances of IB everytime it needs to invoke methods on IB.

Last but not least, there's the `Blueprint Service` that can instantiate complex object graphs using dependency injection, including service proxies, which I have never used and don't feel that I can comment on...

Comment: Thank you for your time. But the question is not about notification but about architecture patterns :)

Comment: Ah, mea culpa - it would depend on the coupling strength between the components. I believe that the first case has weaker coupling, but I have used both cases. In any case (ha!) the `Controller` needs to be an interface.